# PDO ODBC MYSQL : i try to connect and it just gives me a fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, odbc

Im trying to connect to odbc using the following php pdo code

```
$ligacao = new PDO("odbc:Driver={MYSQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver };Server=localhost;Database=samsic; Uid=root;Pwd='';")
```

And it just gives me the following error:

[image: error]

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Instead of including a massive screen shot of the error message, you could have just copy/pasted the message into the question directly.

Comment: You should also show us the code before and after this (is that code on line 4)? Also, do you have a `;` at the end of the real code?

Comment: the code is just that, i just put the image cause it just shows "fatal error on line 5" and people would simple ask for the rest of the error

Comment: So you have a php file with only one line in it, and that line is on line 4? Is that the file `ligacao.php`? Do you at least have an opening PHP-tag? Regarding the error message, if you pasted it in the question and wrote: "This is the complete error message I get", we would have accepted that.

Comment: If this is a MySQL database and PHP why do you think you should use ODBC, its not necessary see [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your database is local, as RiggsFolly said you don't need ODBC.

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "samsic";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = ""; 
try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
    echo 'success';
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```